# What does 'Invalid literal error for int()' mean?

Tags: python-3.x

When I press the button of send sms in list, I get the following error.

> Invalid literal for int() with base 10.

```
@classmethod
@ModelView.button
def send_sms(cls, donation_records):
    for record in donation_records:
        record.save()
        msg_send = record.notify_user_sms('send_sms')

def notify_user_sms(self, message_state):
    if self.dental_pnumber:
      if not self.dental_pnumber:
          self.raise_user_error("Missing Patient Contact Number.")
        contact_to_patient = getattr(self, self.SMS.get(message_state)[0])
        params = {
            # 'msg': 'This is a testing message. Please ignore it.',
            'msg': self.SMS.get(message_state)[1],               
            'mobile': self.dental_pnumber,
        }
        url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/xxxxsms/xxxxsms.aspx"
        requests.get(url, xxxxx)
        return True
```

Comment: on which line of code are you getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
Your variable which is of type int has a "." inside of it. You should use float type instead which can handle a ".".

For example:

```
int('99999.000000')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

and:

```
float('99999.000000')
99999.0
```

But if you still want an int output, you should then use:

```
int(float('99999.000000'))
```

Comment: No number is too big for a Python `int`. The reason why your first example fails is that there is a `.` in it.

Comment: @mkrieger1 *Technically* there *could* be a integer too big but it would have to be bigger than the computers memory (good luck).